# How to set image size with Image Map Plugin on QGIS 2.4?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I use QGIS 2.4, but I have noticed that the "Set Map/Image Size" feature on the HTML Image Map Plugin no longer seems to work. No matter what you set the "Set Map/Image Size" for, your image will always be 928 x 725. This feature worked fine with QGIS 2.2, but I don't want to go back to 2.2, for a variety of reasons.

How do I get this feature to work with 2.4?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the plugin and uploaded a new version to the plugin repository (version 2.0.1 to be precise).
It was actually an old bug, but nobody used that apparently...

All QGIS plugins are written by different authors. Either via plugins.qgis.org or via the info in the plugin manager you can reach the author, of find the place to create issues for that plugin.